# Load xml data from specific nodes

Tags: c#, xml

My xml file is as under

```
<Nodes>
 <Node>
   ..
   ..
 <Node>
 <Node>
   ..
   ..
 <Node>
 <NodeTemplate>
   ..
   ..
 <NodeTemplate>
</Nodes>
```

My main data is in 'Node' elements and the last element is a template. Is there anyway I can ignore the NodeTemplate below?

```
xdoc  = XDocument.Load(ppath);
XElement xmain = xdoc.Element("Nodes");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - ask for just the `Node` elements:

```
var nodes = xdoc.Root.Elements("Nodes");
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    ...
}
```

Or if you want to do lots of work on the doc without `NodeTemplate` getting in the way:

```
xdoc.Root.Elements("NodeTemplate").Remove();
```

... just remember not to save it over the top of the original, as you'll blow away the `NodeTemplate` element...

Answer (score 1):

You can select all `Nodes`elements and then remove `NodeTemplate` nodes like that:

```
 var nodes = xdoc.Elements("Nodes");
 nodes.Elements("NodeTemplate").Remove();
```